# Extract grouped values from a dataframe based on a range of grouped values from another dataframe using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to extract the grouped index values from a dataframe (df1) that represent a range of grouped times (start - end) and that encompass the grouped times given in another dataframe (df2). My required output is df3.

```
df1<-data.frame(group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"),index=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),start=c(5,10,15,20,5,10,15,20,5,10,15,20),end=c(10,15,20,25,10,15,20,25,10,15,20,25))
df2<-data.frame(group = c("A","B","B","C","A","C"),time=c(11,17,24,5,5,22))
df3<-data.frame(time=c(11,17,24,5,5,22),index=c(2,7,8,9,1,12))
```

A previous related question I posted was answered with a neat pipe solution for ungrouped data:

```
    library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    select(from = start, to = end) %>% 
    pmap(seq) %>% 
    do.call(cbind, .) %>% 
    list(.) %>%
    mutate(df2, new = ., 
                ind = map2(time, new, ~ which(.x == .y, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2])) %>%
    select(-new)
```

Can this be modified to group by the 'group' column in both df1 and df2 to give the output df3?

Comment: Please check the 'index' in  'df3'.  It is not clear how you got such a big numbers

Comment: in df3 the required index field contains the first number 2 which is a cross reference from the the 1st row of df2 (A and 11) which corresponds to the 2nd row in df1 (group = A, start = 10, end = 15) which is index 2 (my required output).

Comment: similarly for the larger numbers: the last entry in df2 (C and 22) correspond to the last row in df1 (group = C, start = 20, end = 25) which is index 12 (my required output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `group_by`, we can `nest` and then do a join

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest(-group)  %>%
  mutate(new = map(data, ~.x %>% 
  select(from = start, to = end) %>%
  pmap(seq) %>% 
  do.call(cbind, .) %>% 
  list(.))) %>%
  right_join(df2) %>%
  mutate(ind = map2_int(time, new, ~ which(.x == .y[[1]], arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]),
          ind = map2_dbl(ind, data, ~ .y$index[.x])) %>%
  select(time, ind)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   time   ind
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 11.0   2.00
#2 17.0   7.00
#3 24.0   8.00
#4  5.00  9.00
#5  5.00  1.00
#6 22.0  12.0
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I am looking for but the output gives the wrong indices, i.e. only gives indices for group A

Comment: @AlMac Check your group A, B, and C, it is having the same start/end

Answer (score 1):

Here is something nice with data.table,

```
df1<-data.table(group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"),index=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),start=c(5,10,15,20,5,10,15,20,5,10,15,20),end=c(10,15,20,25,10,15,20,25,10,15,20,25))
df2<-data.table(group = c("A","B","B","C","A","C"),time=c(11,17,24,5,5,22))


df1[df2,on=.(group,start<=time,end>=time)][,c("start","index")]


   start index
1:    11     2
2:    17     7
3:    24     8
4:     5     9
5:     5     1
6:    22    12
```

you can then rename the start column to time and you got your answer i think.

Comment: This is a neat succinct approach but it gives me start times not indices. I am looking for df3 output, i.e. the indices (column 'index') from df1 related to time range  that correspond to matched grouped times from df2.